# BlackBerry 10 OS OpenGL ES 1.1 Application Template

Tags: opengl-es, blackberry-10, blackberry-qnx

I wanted to follow this [tutorial](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/beta/documentation/hello_nativesdk_before_you_begin_1935867_11.html)

But it says to create a BlackBerry 10 OS OpenGL ES 1.1 Application Template Project. But I dont see any option for that when I try to create a new blackberry10 C/C++ project in QNX IDE.

[image]

How do I add this option ?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest tools loaded, when I follow the instructions in the link using the Beta 4 IDE I see:

[image: New BlackBerry C/C++ Project Dialog]

Comment: I downloaded the SDK from blackberry website. How do I add the tools or load them?

Comment: They are included. When did you download the tools?

Comment: Try downloading it from https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/download There seems to be an issue with the NDK without Cascades support sample application wizzard.